# Float items in a taskbar right+left when they are all in a <li> tag

Tags: html, css

My navbar looks like this:
https://ibb.co/rs7Ndr5

I want to add another link to my navbar, "register", which would appear on the far right side.
The only thing is, I made the navbar that there is a

with all of the links, and everything in that list is put in the navbar using css. So if I added the new item into the list, it would be floated left like everything else in the list, because the css puts everything in a

tag into the navbar.

This is my css:

```
<style>
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
background-color: #333;
}
li {
float: left;
border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}
li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}
/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
background-color: #111;
}
/* for buttons*/
.paging {
background-color: #333;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 8px 14px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
button:hover {
background-color: #111;
}
</style>
```

This is the html:

```
<ul>
<li class="all"><a href="/">All videos</a></li>
<li class="stam"><a href="/stam">Stam videos</a></li>
<li class="music"><a href="/music">Music videos</a></li>
<li class="news"><a href="/news">News videos</a></li>
<li class="news"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please help me!
Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you want.  Is it this? https://jsfiddle.net/m19bpehw/

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want to achieve.  You can add a class to the new "register" button and float it to the right.  Like this:

```css
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
background-color: #333;
}
li {
float: left;
border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}
li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}
/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
background-color: #111;
}
/* for buttons*/
.paging {
background-color: #333;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 8px 14px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
button:hover {
background-color: #111;
}

.register {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="all"><a href="/">All videos</a></li>
<li class="stam"><a href="/stam">Stam videos</a></li>
<li class="music"><a href="/music">Music videos</a></li>
<li class="news"><a href="/news">News videos</a></li>
<li class="news"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
<li class="register"><a href="/contact">Register</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly! I really appreciate it!